# Custom UITableViewCell : UITextView being reset after adding attributes

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitableview

I am working on notifications view and i want the user name to be bold and the rest of the message to be not bold. At the moment the username bolds but after this process the rest of the text becomes really small and i cant work out why.

```
let fromUser:PFUser = friendRequests.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("from") as! PFUser

cell.notificationMessage.text =  fromUser.objectForKey("Name") as! String + " has sent you a friend request."

let boldText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cell.notificationMessage.text)
let stringCount = fromUser.objectForKey("Name") as? String
boldText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (stringCount?.characters.count)!))
cell.notificationMessage.attributedText = boldText
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying lenght stringCount? witch is the lenght of the username and not the whole text, try changing the lenght and it should work

Hope it helps

Comment: i only want the username bold, the rest of the text should be the normal system font size 14. But it looks like system font size 8??

Comment: try writing  stringCount.count instead of stringCount?.characters.count

Comment: gives me this error,  'count' is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion